# How to create an AutoSum type of function in an app using c#

Tags: c#, android

Right now I am trying to build an app where a user will be able to type in  numbers in several fields and once a new number has been typed in I want to display the total sum below the fields in a Label.

so if one types in 2 in field1
and 3 in field2
and nothing in field3
and 5 in field4
the label should display 10

Right now I have tried this using Entry as the field but I do not know whether that is the best one.
No matter which type of field I choose it seems they are always set to only accept String and not Integers which means I need to convert from string to Int.
And it just seems like there must be an easier way..

I am using Visual studio for C#

Comment: Your question is way too imprecise to get an answer. Seams like a pretty simple thing you are looking for and you should start by looking into some basic tutorials for Xamarin for android. You have a NumberPicker in android so you can use that for numbers.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
I am trying to build it for an iphone so if there's a way to do it for only Android I'm afraid it won't really hrlp me.
Right now I am using <Entry/> as my field and that means I need to convert whatever is entered, from string to integer. And I also need to be able to recognise if a user puts in a string and count that as 0.
So if a user puts in 500s it will count as 0. And if the Entry is empty it also needs to be counted as 0.

Comment: And there will be about 20 fields so each field needs to get checked if there is an number that can be converted to an integer in there and if there is anything else it needs to equal 0.

Comment: Sorry you really should rewrite the question. What do you mean iPhone you used android for the tag? If you are using Xamarin.Forms make it clear in the question. Best way to do this is using MVVM so you should look into it.